# Complete fields with algebraically closed residue field

Tags: nt.number-theory, fields, class-field-theory, local-fields

I am looking for a reference where the following result is proven:

> Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. If $K$ is a complete and discretely valued field with residue field $k$. Then $K$ is one of the following:
>
> 1) The field of Laurent series in $k$.
>
> 2) A finite and totally ramified extension of a field of Witt vectors with components in $k$.

On another note, Lang later calls any such field from the list as *the complete unramified field with residue field $k$*. Can anyone explain me what does he mean by an *unramified* field (I am only familiar with what an unramified extension is) ? For example, one page later, Lang claims that if we have two such complete unramified fields $K_1\subset K_2$ with respective algebraically closed residue fields $k_1\subset k_2$, then for an intermediate finite extension $K_1\subset E$, with $E/K_1$ totally ramified, one must have $E=K_1$.
I have really tried to find answers for some time on my own, but with no luck.

Comment: In mixed characteristic, a discretely valued field $K$ is called *unramified* if $p$ is a uniformiser in $\mathcal O_K$. I'm not sure if there is a similar notion in pure characteristic, because there is no initial object in this category.

Comment: Some of this material is covered in [Tag 09E3](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09E3), where this notion is called *weakly unramified*, and the extension is *unramified* if moreover the residue extension is separable. This does not agree with the general notion of unramified ring morphisms, because those are usually assumed of finite type, cf. [Tag 00US](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00US). In other sources, you may find different terminology.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Serre, Local fields, Chapter II: II.4 for the first case and II.5 for the second case.